# How to change syntax of chicago.bst

Tags: bibtex, natbib, chicago-style

I use

```
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{mychicago}
\bibliography{XYZ}
```

I modified `Chicago.bst` to `Mychicago.bst` following this description:
[How to remove parentheses from year in the references in chicago bibliography style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108871/how-to-remove-parentheses-from-year-in-the-references-in-chicago-bibliography-st) and I replaced `"{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f.}"` with `"{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, ff}"`, and `"{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}"` with `"{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}"` (under format.names. ,starting on line 387 in the copy of the file).
 [How to do Chicago-style citation where author last name, first name appear in full in bibliography using the natbib and bibtex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324728/how-to-do-chicago-style-citation-where-author-last-name-first-name-appear-in-fu)

Now I have the problem that my bibliography displays dots and commas and the wrong places when there are several authors. e.g

```
@article{Kongsamut,
author = {Piyabha Kongsamut and Sergio Rebelo and Danyang Xie},
journal = {The Review of Economic Studies},
number = {4},
pages = {869-882},
publisher = {Oxford University Press, Review of Economic Studies, Ltd.},
title = {{Beyond Balanced Growth}},
volume = {68},
year = {2001},
}
```

and it gets displayed:

> Kongsamut, Piyabha., Sergio. Rebelo, and Danyang. Xie 2001. Beyond
>   Balanced Growth. The Review of Economic Studies 68(4), 869–882.

I would like it to display like

> Kongsamut, Piyabha, Sergio Rebelo and
>   Danyang Xie. 2001. Beyond Balanced Growth. The Review of Economic
>   Studies 68(4), 869–882.

However, this problem occurs only if there is more than one author. Otherwise it works just fine.

Can someone tell me how to adjust my `.bst` file? thanks!

As indicated by @AlanMunn I did not delete `.`. However, my question still stays open, why there is no dot after the last last name (Xie in this example) and how to add a `comma` after the name of the journal (The Review of Economic Studies in this example)

Comment: Did you forget to remove the `.` in the  changes?  Check your `.bst` file, and you will probably find: `{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, ff.}` instead of `{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, ff}` and  `{ff.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}` instead of `{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}`.

Comment: Yes true, I forgot to remove the ' .'
Still there is no dot between the last name and the year. 
It looks like this: 
Kongsamut, Piyabha, Sergio Rebelo and Danyang Xie 2001. Beyond Balanced Growth. The Review of Economic Studies 68(4), 869–882.

Answer (score 1):

To make the further changes you need you need to do the following.

In the function `output.year.check` add a `". "` before the `year` is output. This will add the `.` after the last name in the list.

```
FUNCTION {output.year.check}
{ year empty$
     { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$ }
     { write$
        ". " year * extra.label * % <------- added ". " here
       month empty$
          { "" * }
          { ", " * month * "" * }
       if$
       mid.sentence 'output.state :=
     }
  if$
}
```

To put a comma after the journal name create a new function. This is a copy of the function `emphasize.space` but adds a comma. (Don't replace the `emphasize.space` function, as it is needed for other things.)  I added this function right after the `emphasize.space` function in the `.bst` file.

```
FUNCTION {emphasize.comma}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "{\em " swap$ * "\/,}" * }
  if$
}
```

Now change the following in the `format.jour.vol` function. (Partial code here).

```
FUNCTION {format.jour.vol}
{ journal empty$
    { "no journal in " cite$ * warning$
      "" }
    { journal emphasize.comma } % changed emphasize.space to emphasize.comma
    if$
```

This should do what you want.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Kongsamut,
author = {Piyabha Kongsamut and Sergio Rebelo and Danyang Xie},
journal = {The Review of Economic Studies},
number = {4},
pages = {869-882},
publisher = {Oxford University Press, Review of Economic Studies, Ltd.},
title = {{Beyond Balanced Growth}},
volume = {68},
year = {2001},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{chicago-ff}

\begin{document}
\cite{Kongsamut}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]